# Dynamically added controls not appearing where expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a page with a Grid on it.

Based on the selection of a ComboBox I dynamically add an appropriate GridView that has a ContextMenu (so far so good).

One of the ContextMenuItem options needs user input so I dynamically build and add controls to a Grid, and add the Grid as a child of the Grid on the Page (at the same time I hide the first child of the Grid (the GridView)).

The controls don't appear in the expected positions. If I specify 0,0,0,0 they show up somewhere around the middle. If I specify -800, -400, 0,0 they show up close to where I want them to be but not where they are expected to be (the Grid itself is 800x400).

Am I missing something?

I've tried adding columns and rows and specifying position that way. I've tried setting margins of the controls directly. Nothing seems to work as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `Canvas` if you are positioning controls exactly. A `Grid` is designed to position controls relatively, whereas it looks like you are trying to position them absolutely (within the `Grid`).

Answer (score 0):

To position the controls you can do it in several ways. You should use `Canvas` element instead of `Grid` and set `Left` and `Top` properties in controls you want to position.
Sample in XAML to position button in *(30, 10)*:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="sampleButton" 
            Width="30" Height="20" 
            Canvas.Left="30" 
            Canvas.Top="10"/>
</Canvas>
```

Sample in code behind:

```
...
Canvas.SetLeft(sampleButton, 30);
Canvas.SetTop(sampleButton, 10);
...
```

If you, however, need to use `Grid` (for some reason), you can set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Top`, specify appropriate values for `Width` and `Height` and THEN set Margin to *x, y, 0, 0*.
A sample code:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="sampleButton" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="30" Height="20" 
            Margin="30, 10, 0, 0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have been using HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment and those didn't help. There is no reason for me to not use Canvas. That seems to work.

Comment: It works inside a cell of a `Grid` where the control is defined. In my example there is a `Grid` with one row and one column, so it's working as it was the whole `Grid` container. If you have defined some rows and columns in your `Grid`, you should consider this.